# Tratar desconexão de socket em clients

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Por exemplo:

1. Eu tenho 5 dispositivos móveis ouvindo os eventos
2. Um dispositivo perdeu a conexão
3. O servidor dispara um evento
4. Quatro dispositivos conectados recebem o evento
5. O dispositivo desconectado perde o evento e logo em seguida reconecta

Ele deve receber o evento perdido.

Mas o servidor não sabe quais clients não receberam seu evento.
O que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Você tem um banco de dados? Você mantém algum registro dos dispositivos conectados?

Comment: Sim tenho banco de dados e uma API rest também para outras rotinas do app, mas não guardo os dispositivos conectados no banco.

Comment: Se você guardar no banco fica bem fácil, senão você vai ter que manter um array com identificações  no seu servidor

Comment: Mas além de guardar os clients conectados eu teria que fazer os clients avisarem o servidor se receberam o evento, aí o servidor enviaria novamente para que não avisou, seria algo assim?